# Formula o VBA para poner rango de numeros basandose en otra columna

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo esta tabla en Excel:

[image: Tabla 1 - Inicial]

He probado con fórmulas y no logro hacer lo siguiente:
En la columna NUEVO, debe ponerse del 1 al 5, pero los valores iguales juntos deben llevar el mismo valor nuevo. Debe quedar en el mismo orden que yo tengo ANTIGUO.

**Debería quedar así:**

[image: Tabla 2 - Resultado]

Nótese que no existe ningún patrón que yo pueda usar para poner un valor en NUEVO y el máximo siempre será 5.

Creo que esto se puede hacer usando VBA, pero mis conocimiento en este lenguaje son casi nulos. Aunque tengo la opción de hacerlo manualmente, son más de 700.000 filas que debo procesar y pues tomara muchísimo tiempo.
Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenté buscar una fórmula.
Usando:

```
=SI(IGUAL(A1;A2);B1;SI(MAYOR.O.IGUAL(SUMA(B1+1);6);1;SUMA(B1+1)))
```

Consigo un el resultado que pides. El único requisito es que esta formula necesita que el primer indice da la columna **nueva** no sea nulo.

[image: Salida]

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! Me funciono.